# White rot on some of my onions do I need to lift the whole crop

Tags: onions

I have lifted a couple of my onions today that had gone a little dry and have discovered white rot on the roots, I lifted another and this one has no sign.

Do I need to lift the whole crop straight away or can I watch carefully and lift onions if I think they are suffering? In addition is it safe to cure and eat onions that have a minor amount of white rot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White rot spreads easily through the soil so you want to minimize soil movement with shoes/watering. I don't recommend eating onions that have fungus but if you remove the rotten part and the area around it, it might be fine.

Comment: Spoke to 2 old timers at my allotment yesterday, they advised tugging the onions, any that come away easily from the soil pull out as they are prob having there roots attacked already and leave the firm ones on but just test them every day or so. Pulled out about 2/3 of my crop, about 25 onions, only 5 of them have the mound on he base and of those when we chopped them 3 had only got it on the surface so we cut the bad part away. Rest are drying now see what I get out of them.